# Drop valores de um dataframe baseado em um valor booleano

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quando leio um arquivo CSV, essas são as 5 primeiras linhas:

```
     Shape Reported             Time
1          OTHER  6/30/1930 20:00
3           DISK   6/1/1931 13:00
4          LIGHT  4/18/1933 19:00
5           DISK  9/15/1934 15:30
6         CIRCLE   6/15/1935 0:00
```

Eu quero dar um drop em todos os valores que sejam iguais a 'OTHER', na coluna Shape Reported, mas quando eu tento isso:

```
ufo.drop(ufo['Shape Reported'] == 'OTHER', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Eu recebo esse erro:

```
  File "C:\CursoPython\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5591, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[False False False ... False False False] not found in axis'
```

Tem algum jeito de usar o drop para fazer isso? Se sim, é possível não utilizar o ILOC, tentando fazer algo similar ao que eu fiz?

Answer (score 1):

É possível realizar esta tarefa sem utilizar o **drop**, selecionado as linhas de interesse.

```
ufo = ufo[ufo["Shape Reported "] != "OTHER"]
```

Assim o novo **ufo** terá todas as linhas, com exeção daquelas que conter "OTHER" na coluna "Shape Reported"

Este tipo de seleção se chama **Boolean indexing**, aqui tem [na documentação do Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) tem a explicação detalhada, esta em inglês mas você pode utilizar a tradução do próprio navegador se precisar.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!